# powershell script to compare two text files and output should be a notification like email

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm having a PowerShell script for comparing two text files and displaying the output:

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content c:\scripts\x.txt) $(Get-Content c:\scripts\y.txt) -includeequal
```

But I want the output in the form of a notification, like an Email...

How can I forward the output to an Email-Body and then send it the mail?

Comment: yes it's possible, have a look at [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @LoïcMICHEL, Thanks a lot will check and try with these options

Answer (score 1):

To put the output comparison into an Email and send it over gmail, you can use the Send-MailMessage command like this:

```
$From = "YourEmail@gmail.com"
$To = "ToMail@Domain.com"
$Cc = "CCMail@Domain.com"
$Subject = "String Comparison"
$comparison = (Compare-Object (Get-Content c:\scripts\x.txt) (Get-Content c:\scripts\y.txt) -includeequal).InputObject
foreach($line in $comparison)
{
  $Body+= $line
}
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

For more information look into [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) and [Google SMTP Config](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=de)

Comment: I'm using the same script in Chef cookbook and i'm getting the error like this " Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' t
o the type
    'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported." And (i'm new to PowerShell) Can you please help me on this.....

Comment: That means that what ever you are trying to add as the Body isnt a string (probaly you are pushing an array) try to convert your output to an string before trying to send the mail.

Comment: Sorry on 22 Dec I have attend a meeting and I didn't check the code. Today I checked and getting the same error.
 Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
                  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
Can you please check and give the solution.. It's a great help for me..

Comment: @venky
It works for me, what is the output of $Body and of $Body.GetType() ?